# Rails does not route to root 'welcome.index'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ruby -v = 2.1.6p336

rails -v = 4.2.1

MySQL --version = 14.14

New to programming and Rails.   Going through tutorials.

did `rails generate controller welcome index`.

Rails Server  - localhost:3000 shows Welcome aboard page.

Change config/routes.rb file...  un-comment out  root 'welcome#index'    (got rid of the #.    (line 8)
Rails Server  - localhost:3000 shows error.

----------copied from localhost:3000------------------------------------------

```
ExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#index
Showing c:/row/dev/readit/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
Rails.root: c:/row/dev/readit

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___173287605_49138164'
```

---

commented the root 'welcome#index' out again, and I have the Welcome Aboard page back.

If I execute localhost:3000/index
I get a routing error.     No route matches [GET] "/index"

I have:

```
controllers/welcome_controller.rb
views/welcome/index.html.erb
```

this is the start of the config/routes.rb file -----------------

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'welcome#index'
```

---

How do I get the `config/routes.rb` file to display the `views/welcome/index.html.erb` file?

Does this have anything to do with the MySQL socket I'm suppose to put in the `config/database.yml`  ?    Because I don't what to put there.

Comment: Seriously, get a better tutorial. None of the good ones leave you with such a fundamentally broken thing as your `javascript_include_tag` not working. My recommendation is to use the resources on the Rails website: http://rubyonrails.org/documentation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is an error at line 6 on "application.html.erb". If you want to create a hyperlink from that page to the "root" page, you should use the following view helper:

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
```

When the page is rendered and you check the HTML code using the Chrome's inspector, you will see that above code is converted to:

```
<a href="/welcome/index">Home</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response Yosep Kim.   here is line 6 of that file       <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>       Do I replace it with what you show?  Or just add that line?

Comment: If my answer helped you, I appreciated if you could mark it as answer. Thanks. And, also, Welcome to Rails! It takes some time to understand and embrace Rails conventions, but once you do, it's so much fun and fast to build applications.

Comment: OK... so I took out line 6 and replaced it with      <%= link_to "Home", root_path %>       and its working perfectly.     Thanks for your help Yosep Kim.

Comment: No problem, Chuck. It looks like you are new to Rails. If so, Welcome! Rails is really awesome, and I hope you enjoy it and make some good money!~

Comment: Yes I am new to Rails... and it is making me feel really dense.   But I'm also stubborn, and will keep working at it as it slowly sinks in.   This is a great place to get help.

Answer (score 0):

In your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`, try changing the line:

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', data-turbolinks-track => true %>`

To this (removing the `data-turbolinks-track => true`):

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>`

That might fix it. You shouldn't remove the entire line as it's likely you'll need JS available in your layout at some point in the project :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Didn't work for me.   Using Yosep Kim's line in place of my original line 6 worked.       I inserted a new line       <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>,    but had to remove it because it crashed the program.     Now the file has nothing about javascript in it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by renaming my [It may not sound correct but it worked for me , give it a try]

app/views/layouts/**application**.html.erb

TO

app/views/layouts/**default**.html.erb

I hope it works for you as well